# Channel form css overrides my css?

Tags: channel

Channel form css overrides my css. Ruining the consistent layout across the site.

Is it supposed to be like that? How can I have my style on the submit button for example?

Thanks,
L.

Answer (score 2):

Simply apply greater significant specificity in your CSS rules that you want to lay on your form. This is a simple part of CSS. Here is an example:

```
// The forms theme 
.form .button {
    color: red;
}

// Your button theme, adding greater specificity if needed
.button,
.my-page-body .form .button {
    color: blue;
}
```

This is really more of a CSS answer than EE answer.

You can set a class on your Channel Form using a param:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_form/index.html#class
And just apply your styles to that class:

```
{exp:channel:form
    class="my-form-class"
    ...}

    <button class="button" />

{/exp:channel:form}

...

// Form styles
.my-form-class .button {
    color: blue;
}
```

Another option is to disable including EE form assets using a param on the Channel Form:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_form/index.html#include-assets
This can be dicey if you are using complex fields in the Channel Form instead of simple text/text-area fields.

Any of these options could work for you; you'll need to be a lot more specific in your use case to recommend one option over another, and I doubt I covered all of them in this answer.